# Multi Touch [Android]

Tags: java, android, multi-touch

I my code, severely simplified is the following:

```
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();
    }
    else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();
    }
    else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();
    }
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN){
        x2 = me.getX(1);
        y2 = me.getY(1);
    }
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP){
        x2 = me.getX(1);
        y2 = me.getY(1);
    }
```

I want to add

```
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_MOVE){
        x2 = me.getX(1);
        y2 = me.getY(1);
    }
```

But of course

```
   MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_MOVE
```

Is not a real methode.  I know there has to be a way around this.   Any suggestions?

If you don't understand my question, what I am asking is, is there a multi-touch methode that runs when a pointer is moved?  BTW googles not being helpful.

I also checked http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html but again nothing useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The order in which individual pointers appear within a motion event is
>   undefined. Thus the pointer index of a pointer can change from one
>   event to the next but the pointer id of a pointer is guaranteed to
>   remain constant as long as the pointer remains active. Use the
>   getPointerId(int) method to obtain the pointer id of a pointer to
>   track it across all subsequent motion events in a gesture. Then for
>   successive motion events, use the findPointerIndex(int) method to
>   obtain the pointer index for a given pointer id in that motion event.

You must get and track the pointer IDs yourself and determine which pointer(s) moved.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html